# IE Fallback for Hover animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to put together a fallback in Internet Explorer for hovering over an element.

In Chrome, the element `pops` and looks neat but not in IE :(

Currently there is a time delay before the background colour appears.

I'm guessing `-webkit-animation-name` is the root of my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/8j249sre/

```
<div class="effects">
    <a class="hvr-pop" href="#">Pop</a>
</div>


/* Pop */
@-webkit-keyframes hvr-pop {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-pop {
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
  }
}

.hvr-pop {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.hvr-pop:hover, .hvr-pop:focus, .hvr-pop:active {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-pop;
  animation-name: hvr-pop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Comment: Please specify the version of IE that exhibits this problem. Tested with IE11, behaves identically to Chrome.

Comment: @Serlite Good idea! Having the issue in IE11 :-)

Comment: You know that your fiddle contains no css animations right?

Comment: @somethinghere Good spot :-D But you're still able to hover in Chrome, yes? I am storing these externally :)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help us as you are asking for help on css animations, but there are none...

Comment: @somethinghere I'd be happy to move the external files to the CSS panel if it would help matters :-)

Comment: If you mind, is it possible to get this into a SO snippet? Just simplify the problem and only include the animation that you are testing with so we can see where it might be an issue.

Comment: @somethinghere Updated Fiddle & OP: http://jsfiddle.net/8j249sre/1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding this to my `.hvr-pop:hover, .hvr-pop:focus, .hvr-pop:active {` resolved my issue :-)

`-ms-animation-name:none;`

Comment: @Charles Not enough detail in my opinion. I have 2 days for this answer to be accepted and frankly detail is necessary in this timeframe.

Comment: Then I guess my real question is why aren't you adding the detail now?